# Strategies to preserve disk space in high input frequency application

Tags: database, embedded-linux, diskspace, shrink, vacuum

I have a requirement to support shrinking of a database which has a data entry rate of 1 entry (approx. 300KB) per second. The database file can reach 3GB. The current database has no auto vacuum feature. Database file space going over a certain limit (say 3GB) is worst-case scenario.

My current strategy is to delete the oldest data (by clustered primary key), and then to CHECKPOINT DEFRAG. This does not seem to be reliable, and the VACUUM or DEFRAG can take a long time. I don't want to name database names but I am open to suggestions.

I was wondering what other strategies might be available to reliably (little to no downtime, O(1) operation speed) preserve disk space.

EDIT: Relational database required as reporting and SQL data extraction is necessary.

Fixed-size circular buffer - exactly - I need to replicate this in the relational world, using a low footprint DB, and fast "circular" behaviour (i.e fast inserts)

Comment: Please list some requirements. Do you really need relational database? etc

Comment: Its obvious you want something along the lines of a fixed-size circular-buffer. Once the database file reaches your size-limit (3GB) why don't you simply start overwriting the oldest entries with the new data entries. If you provide more details of the database framework being used, someone will be able to suggest the proper implementation.

Comment: Does the data (300Kb) need to be in the database? - If the data can be stored separately (e.g. a 3Gb circular file), then the database would probably behave nicely

Answer (score 1):

1) Determine how many rows of data you can store with your requirements.

2) Use a primary key that is an integer related to #1.

3) Create a way to track the primary key usage, example, store primary key and timestamp of usage in separate table.

4) When inserting always grab the oldest primary key that was used, and update that row with the new data.

If implemented properly, this will limit the # of rows to what you specify in #1.